# Populate HashMap Failure

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to create a HashMap in Java and populate it with `.put()` method. The reflection of eclipse confused me.

At the beginning I initialize the HashMap in the following manner, but It seems that `.put()` is not accessible for the hashMap object.

```
public class NewMap {
    Map<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put(10, "Amir");
    hashMap.put(20, "Bob");
}
```

Then I attempted to add a pair of curly brackets, and it works.

```
public class NewMap {
    Map<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    {
        hashMap.put(10, "Amir");
        hashMap.put(20, "Bob");
    }
}
```

I tried to figure out the mechanism behind it but failed. All the related classes are properly imported. Could anyone kindly cast light on it?

Comment: Your code needs to be in a block, hence why the latter compiles.

Comment: You can only initialize a class field within a code block. Code block are within { ...}.
It could be a method or constructor or within { ... } just as you did.

Comment: [Don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1553851)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have done is a method call, it can only be done inside a block.

The class has state and behavior. Behavior means a certain action or some activity your class can perform. State maintained by fields. The outside region of the block '{ }' in the class is used for state declaration and '{}' used for behavior.

Example, 
you define any function and call it where you have initialized your hashmap.
you will get below runtime error, 
"invalid method declaration; return type required method();"